# string set to null when pushing detail view

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, null, plist

I am pushing a detail view from the master of a Master-Detail Application template.
I want to load a single view with different information depending on which row was clicked. I plan to load the data from a plist file.
Here is the code I used in the MasterViewController, when I added `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
dvc.rowItem = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
NSLog(@"row is %i", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"master %@", dvc.rowItem);
```

where rowItem is an `NSString` belonging to the `DetailViewController`. Inside the `viewDidLoad` of the `DetailViewController` I put:

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@" thingy %@", rowItem);
[self setup:rowItem];
```

and `setup` looks like this:

```
-(void) setup: (NSString *)eval {

filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",eval];
NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSString *subName;
NSString *yesNo;
NSString *theseChanges;
subName = [plistDict objectForKey:@"subContractAddress"];
yesNo = [plistDict objectForKey:@"yesOrno"];
theseChanges = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Changes"];
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *finishedButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *changes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *test;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *finishedLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *subContractName;
@property BOOL needsChanges;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *rowItem;
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender;
@end
```

when I build and run I get the console output of:

```
thingy (null)
(null).plist
row is 0
master Excavations
```

when I press the first row, and

```
thingy (null)
(null).plist
row is 1
master Flooring
```

so somehow, rowItem is getting set to null in the crossover.
Can someone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please post your detail view's interface also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your two log statements as follows:

```
NSLog(@"master %@, detail %@", dvc.rowItem, dvc);

NSLog(@" thingy %@ in detail %@", rowItem, self);
```

I suspect that the detail you create as `dvc` is not the same object that is in the view controller hierarchy.  Showing the object addresses should verify whether that's the answer.

Comment: you were right, they did not have the same memory address. Could you tell me how to allocate the detail view inside the master view?

Comment: It depends on how your original detail controller was created...the one that executes `viewDidLoad:`.  Do you initialize it through a storyboard segue or in the app delegate or some other way?  (It can also be different whether this is iPhone or if there's an iPad split view controller involved.)

Comment: is there a way for me to initialize the 'dvc' with a method such as `initWithMemoryAddress:` ?

Comment: No.  You need to use the object that already exists and update it with the new `rowItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Do your setup in "viewWillAppear" and I'll bet it starts working.

Comment: I put the `viewWillAppear` in the detail and put the code from the setup method into it, but I still get the same output of null

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this,

```
dvc.rowItem = [[NString alloc]initWithString:@"%@",[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: i still get the output of null :(

Comment: @Jeeter: how you displayed the detailview? please post that code too.